# Azure - creating Boolean variables and use it across multiple tasks

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I want to define one Boolean variable for a stage and want to set it(True/False) inside another script in one of the task in the stage and want to use that variable as a condition in other subsequent tasks, How can I do it?

My azure pipeline is YAML based.

Comment: Hi, is there any update for this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to define one Boolean variable for a stage and want to set
>   it(True/False) inside another script in one of the task in the stage
>   and want to use that variable as a condition in other subsequent
>   tasks, How can I do it?

Here's one example:

```
stages:
- stage: Build
  variables: 
    Key : false
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    continueOnError: true
    steps:
    - script: echo Key:'$(Key)'

    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          # Write your PowerShell commands here.

          Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Key;]true"

    - task: CmdLine@2
      inputs:
        script: echo Key:'$(Key)'

    - task: CmdLine@2
      condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Key'], 'true'))
      inputs:
        script: |
          echo Write your commands here

          echo Hello world
```

I have one stage variable `Key`, its value is false. Then in PS task I use `task.setvariable` to override the key's value. **Note:** This way the new value `true` is a job-scope value. If you have more than one jobs in one stage, this can't work well.

Update1:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        filePath: 'Test.ps1'
```

My Test.ps1:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Key;]true"
```

Comment: What if my script type is file path not inline? I want to call a script and want to update the variable inside the script and reuse it in next task set

Comment: @BiswajitMaharana No matter inline or file path, this way both works.

Comment: And if you want the new value works across jobs in your stage, check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-a-multi-job-output-variable), to set `isOutput=true` is enough.

Comment: Just to understand the syntax of override the key here. If I have multiple variables, then how can I override both of them.
Also if you can give an example of file path with either shell or perl script or any other script with how can we override them,  I can get clarified more.

Comment: Just create a script file in azure devops repos, move the content from inline script to it, it should work.

Comment: Okay understood. Don't we have to pass the variable inside ```arguments``` tag under ```inputs```?

Comment: @BiswajitMaharana In `file path` way,  If you want to use variables defined outside the script itself, like pipeline variables/stage variables, we have to use `arguments` as the bridge.

Comment: @BiswajitMaharana The arguments for file path way are mostly used when we want the script in one .ps1 file to access the outside varaibles. For the simple sample in your original question, it's not necessary...

Comment: I have very similar setup as you, but for some reason, updating the boolean variable's value within the powershell script isn't working for me: "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Key;]true"  << doing this with other, string variables works fine.  But it doesn't seem to be updating my boolean variables...